# Detect cURL timeout in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to detect when a cURL request times out. I'm using curl_multi_exec if this makes a difference?

The output of curl_errno() is 0 which suggests it was a success. However the output of curl_error() is:

> Operation timed out after 1435 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes
>   received

Any ideas why the error code is good, but the error message exists? I would expect an error code of 28 for a timeout.

Also, is there anything I can check in curl_getinfo() for a timeout?

I'm using PHP 5.4.4 / cURL 7.24.0.

Edit 1 - Sample code:

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$a);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$b);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,...);

do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) == -1) usleep(100);
    do { $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active); }
    while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}
```

Comment: can you post your cURL code

Comment: Sure - added it above. Ta!

Comment: Not sure why that is happening that way.  You could specify a timeout to try to force an error using `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` or `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS`.

Comment: I'm forcing it as it is with 1 second. Seems to be enough to get the error message. CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS results in the same behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `curl_multi_exec()`, you'll need to use [`curl_multi_info_read()`](http://php.net/curl_multi_info_read) to get the error code for specific handles.  This is due to the way PHP interfaces with cURL in its easy and multiple interfaces, and how error codes are fetched on individual handles from cURL's [curl_multi_info_read()](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_info_read.html) function (see explanation below).

Basically, if you are using multi handles, calling `curl_errno()` and `curl_error()` are not reliable or accurate.

See this modified example from the [manual](http://php.net/curl_multi_info_read#example-4306):

```
<?php

$urls = array(
   "http://www.cnn.com/",
   "http://www.bbc.co.uk/",
   "http://www.yahoo.com/",
   'http://wijgeiwojgieowjg.com/',
   'http://www.example.com/',
);

$infos = array();

$mh = curl_multi_init();

foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
    $conn[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    if (strpos($url, 'example.com') !== false) {
        // set a really short timeout for one url
        curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 10);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $conn[$i]);
}

do {
    $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

    if (($info = curl_multi_info_read($mh)) !== false) {
        $infos[$info['handle']] = $info;
    }

} while ($status === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $active);

foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
    $info = $infos[$conn[$i]];

    echo "$url returned code {$info['result']}";
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') >= 0) {
        echo ": " . curl_strerror($info['result']);
    }
    echo "\n";

    if ($info['result'] === 0) {
        $res[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($conn[$i]);
    }

    curl_close($conn[$i]);
}
```

Output:

> http://www.cnn.com/ returned code 0
>
> http://www.bbc.co.uk/ returned code 0
>
> http://www.yahoo.com/ returned code 0
>
> http://wijgeiwojgieowjg.com/ returned code 6
>
> http://www.example.com/ returned code 28

**Explanation:**

Specifically, this is due to how PHP's `curl_exec()` calls cURL's `curl_easy_perform` which returns a CURLcode (error code) and PHP specifies the cURL option [CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTERRORBUFFER) which causes a buffer to automatically get filled with an error message if one occurs.

But when using PHP's `curl_multi_exec()`, PHP calls cURL's `curl_multi_perform` which returns immediately and doesn't return error codes for the multi handles.  You must call cURL's `curl_multi_info_read` function to get error codes for the individual handles.

PHP 5.5.0 provides a wrapper to cURL's [`curl_easy_strerror()`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_strerror.html) which returns a string corresponding to a curl error code.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Just what I needed. However, I currently use `curl_getinfo` to check the response HTTP code. But this is not safe to do so? I'm trying to check for intermittent network issues which result in 500 returned for some requests.

Comment: Using `curl_getinfo` is fine for getting info (e.g. HTTP response code) from one of the individual handles.  If the individual handle had an error condition returned from `curl_multi_info_read` some or all of the info from curl_getinfo may not be populated or relevant though.

Answer (score 0):

This can be really frustrating to debug as the documentation and examples on php.net are really poor relating to async curl.

Here is some example code to help demonstrate what DOES work when it comes to curl_multi_exec:

```
// Main work loop

do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while($status = curl_multi_info_read($mh)) {
    if($status['msg'] == CURLMSG_DONE) {

        $errno = $status['result'];
        $errstr = curl_strerror($errno);

        if($errno == CURLE_OK) {

            // This request completed successfully

            // Do something with the info
            $info = curl_getinfo($status['handle');

        } else {

            // There was an error handling this request,
            // like a timeout or something.
            // Note: curl_errno($ch) will probably say success
            // but it's lying to you. Ignore it.

            fwrite(STDERR, "Request failed: Error($errno): $errstr\n");

        }
    }
}
```

With a main work loop like the above, you can then call it as many times as you need to.  Something like

```
while($this->workRemaining()) {
    $this->work();
    usleep(100); // Sleep, or better yet do something productive
}
```

I'm not going to print out the entire class.  You can make it do what you want.

The important part is to check `$status['result']` to determine if there was an error.  Never rely on `curl_getinfo($ch)` as it is wrong in a multi_curl environment.